Pressure seems too high for desired sag in Trek's Thru Shaft shock
I have the stock RockShox Super Deluxe Ultimate Thru Shaft (Trek's proprietary design) shock in my gen 5 Trek Slash 8. I have always used sag to set it up without giving pressure values too much thought, but recently I decided to use Trek's online calculator to see what pressure it recommends.
For my 72kg (gear included), the calculator recommends 176psi, but with this shock pressure I bottom out by just sitting on the bike. To achieve about 30% sag (typical starting point for enduro bikes) I need to pump it up to about 230-240psi.
I understand suspension settings are to a large degree personal preference, but the difference between recommended and realistic pressure seems too large in this case.

Is this a strong indicator that there is something wrong with the shock?
If so, are there typical root causes that I could look into?


Another option - something wrong with your pressure gauge.

Maybe the calculator uses old shock reference data and has never been updated on the website. I wouldn’t think too hard about it.

Do you know how many volume reducers you have in the shock? Having more of them will yield higher sag values at a given pressure.

@VladimirFГероямслава I thought about that but for the fork the values the calculator provides are quite close to what I'm using, so I tend to believe the gauge is ok.

@MaplePanda I assumed the bike shipped without tokens in the shock but I think it's worth a check. Thank you for the suggestion.

Were you cycling the shock (gentle, short compressions) periodically as you brought it up to pressure?

@PaulH Yes, I tried that too.
